# how can find gap time inside time series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, time-series

I have some sensors in some places, for example I have 7 places and in each of them i have 5 sensors:

```
p1 , ... , p7
```

and

```
s1_1, s1_2, ... ,s7_4, s7_5
```

each sensor can send many signal in same time, then for example i have for s1_3 start time and end time.

My data set is like this:

```
id | place | sensor | start_time | end_time
```

some time this sensors have problem and haven't send any signal. i want find this gap time for each sensor and each place.

if the data be some thing like this:

```
id  | palce | sensor | start_time | end_time
1   | p1    | s1_1  | 3/16/20 16:32 | 3/16/20 16:35
2   | p1    | s1_1  | 3/16/20 16:25 | 3/16/2020 16:33
3   | p1    | s1_1  | 3/16/2020 16:40   | 3/16/2020 16:45
```

the output will be this:

```
palce | sensor | start_time | end_time
p1  | s1_1  | 3/16/2020 16:36   | 3/16/2020 16:39
```

I want use spark or pandas for this.

how can i implement this?

Comment: It'll be easier if you provide some dummy input data and your expected output.

Comment: I agree with Allen. Also let us know specifically about the time format that you have for each sensor.

Comment: thanks @Allen . because i have not real data i add a sample for one sensor.